# Magento 2: Advanced Custom Fields for CMS Pages

Tags: magento2, cms, custom

As in Wordpress, we have https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/.

So in Magento 2 we have http://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/download-acm-extension-m2.html

It helps Customer/Client to Manage their CMS Page WithOut knowing HTML/Technical Knowledge.

Is there any better way to manage this using a Free plugin of Customization?

Comment: It seems that Advanced Content Manager is the only one to provides a system as Wordpress does. However there are some free blog extensions available that you can extends..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this may come handy for anyone who is looking for ACF for magento 2 
https://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/documentation/m2/repeater-fields